# ftp_connect using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I need to select an .xml file contents from an ftp location.

```
$source = "TEST.xml";

$target = fopen("TEST2.xml", "w");
```

My ftp ip is 170.201.226.120

I tried these

1. `$conn = ftp_connect(ftp."170.201.226.120") or die("Could not connect");`
2. `$loc="170.201.226.120";`

   `$conn = ftp_connect(ftp.$loc) or die("Could not connect");`
3. `$server=gethostbyaddr("170.201.226.120");`

   `$conn = ftp_connect(ftp.$server) or die("Could not connect");`

But all these shows error or could not connect.

I need to execute these steps follwed by above,

```
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");
ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);
```

Please anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the host. Don't try to append it to the `ftp` constant, whatever that is.

```
$conn = ftp_connect("170.201.226.120") or die("Could not connect");
```

Comment: Hi Quentin, I tried it. But the problem remains. Do I need to add ftp users and account from control panel. Now using that details I can login to the location and upload files.

Answer (score 0):

remove this word:

"ftp." that you add everywhere .

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts are too complex :-) Think more simple!

The php manual of the ftp routines clearly states as syntax for the ftp_connect command:

```
resource ftp_connect ( string $host [, int $port = 21 [, int $timeout = 90 ]] )
```

So simply try this:

```
$conn = ftp_connect("170.201.226.120") or die("Could not connect");
```

That's all there is.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set up a connection 
$conn = ftp_connect("170.201.226.120"); 

// Now Login 
if (ftp_login($conn, $username, $password))
  echo "Success";
  ftp_fget($conn,$target,$source,FTP_ASCII);
else
  echo "Could not Connect";
```

If you still get errors check your FTP port number and modify the first line to :

```
$conn = ftp_connect("170.201.226.120", $port_number);
```

Comment: From the documentation: host: The FTP server address. This parameter shouldn't have any trailing slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://.

Comment: Oh yes .... force of habit ... "ftp://" is to be appended to a TLD. An ip does not need any decoration. Thanks for pointing that out. Answer corrected.

Comment: No. The first argument of `ftp_connect` is the host, it isn't a URI, so it shouldn't ever have `ftp://` prepended, even if you are using a host name and not an ip address. It certainly shouldn't be "appended to a TLD" since `.com.ftp://` would be ridiculous.